# Finding value between ranges without going through the entire ranges

Tags: php

I want to grant bonuses to my players based on how many friends they have.

I have breakpoints (for example 0, 1, 5, 10, 25)

For 0 friends he gets 0 bonus.

For 1 friend he gets 1000, for 5 or above 2000 etc...

What I do right now is this:

```
public function getFriendsBonusByFriendsAmount($amount)
{
    switch (true) {
        case ($amount < 1):
            return 0;
        case ($amount < 5):
            return 1000;
        case ($amount < 10):
            return 2000;
        case ($amount < 25):
            return 3000;
        case ($amount >= 25):
            return 5000;
    }
}
```

**I'm looking for a different way to find the bonus without foreach/switch**

Perhaps think of an array or arrays that I could play with?

```
$bonusBreakpoints = [
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1000,
    5 => 2000,
    10 => 3000,
    25 => 5000
]
```

Or perhaps two arrays with respective indexs?

I thought of a way to do it but it's a memory waste:

```
$bonusPerFriends = [
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1000,
    2 => 1000,
    3 => 1000,
    4 => 1000,
    5 => 2000,
    6 => 2000,
    ...
    25 => 5000
]
```

I rather not to use that way.

Comment: I think the better is store this values in database. And you get the good value for one user when you make your SQL query. (something like `where user = 1 and friend = 5`)

Comment: If you are making `a > x > b`, i.e., always cheking values within a range, then you must cicle between each range... since, you can be in more than one range at a time

Comment: @Bonatti in this case you can't be in the same range twice. 0, 1-4, 5-14, 15-24, 25+

Comment: Not in your case, since you are even returning in the middle of the function.... What I meant was, when you check for a range, it is expected that you check from a point to another. Since your "rule" is non-linear, and not a mathematical function, then you should use `switches`, chained `if-elses`, `foreach`, or any other logic to apply it.

Comment: How many entries are there likely to be? estimate? 10, 30, 100, 500 etc.

Comment: If your *actual* estimate is 25 items then it's definitely not a memory waste. Memory is a lot cheaper than CPU cycles. No need to have the server constantly recalculate it. Your refusal to use loops also seems silly - why? If you really care that much about micro-optimization then stop using a language like PHP.

Comment: Also, if you search from the highest value downward then you don't need a range test. It is just a `$reqdValue >= $currentLowestLimit ...`. i.e. you search half the array on average. It will be fast with a `foreach` for small arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the answer and more research I concludes that binary search is my best option.

The data should look somewhat like this:

```
$bonuses = [
    [ 'min' => 0, 'max' => 0, 'amount' => 0 ]
    [ 'min' => 1, 'max' => 4, 'amount' => 1000 ]
    [ 'min' => 5, 'max' => 14, 'amount' => 2000 ]
    ...
    [ 'min' => 25, 'max' => PHP_INT_MAX, 'amount' => 5000 ]
]
```

You start at the `count($bonuses)/2` and from there check whether you are below the min, is so goes halfway, otherwise check if you are above max, and go halfway there. else... just return the bonus coz you are between the right range.

Since most of my users don't have any friends or more than 25 I would probably check the first and last cell first.

Answer (score 0):

<s>@andrey-mischenko 's answer is technically right, but does not solve the problem *without foreach*, as you said in your question.</s> (Edit: answer was removed) Try this:

```
$bonusBreakpoints = [
    0 => 0,
    1 => 1000,
    5 => 2000,
    10 => 3000,
    25 => 5000
];

$justTheKeys = array_keys($bonusBreakpoints);    

public function getFriendsBonusByFriendsAmount($amount)
{
    $bonus = array_reduce($justTheKeys, function($carryOver, $item) use ($amount)
        {
            if ($amount >= $item) return $bonusBreakpoints($item);

            return $carryOver;
        }
    return $bonus;
}
```

(I'm aware that this is not what `array_reduce` is originally intended for. I understood the question as a mind-game. Like "find creative ways to solve this problem apart from the obvious ones, like loops or switches." If I had to code this for work, I'd probabely use a loop, too. :) )

Comment: Not too shabby, but not elegant either.
I still would rather save the ranges and use binary search to avoid looping than this solution. Question is, which php function uses binary search..

Comment: There is no native one, afaik... here is a pretty good example-implementation, both recursive and iterative: http://infopotato.com/blog/index/binary_search

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes `foreach/switch` will be **the best** solution :)

```
/**
 * Calculates bonus based on how many 
 * friends the player have from predefined breakpoints 
 **/
function getBonus($friends) {
    $bonuses = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000];
    $stops   = [[PHP_INT_MIN, 0], [1, 4], [5, 14], [15, 24], [25, PHP_INT_MAX]];

    // replace the stops by bonus if match, otherwise return empty - O(n)
    $bonus = array_map(function ($stop, $bonus) use ($friends) { 
        if ($friends >= $stop[0] && $friends <= $stop[1]) { 
            return $bonus;
        } 
    }, $stops, $bonuses);

    // clean up the array from empty values - O(n)
    $bonus = array_filter($bonus , 'is_numeric');

    // from array(3 => 3000) to 3000 - O(1)
    return array_pop($bonus); 
}
```

**results:**

```
echo getBonus(0).PHP_EOL;  // 0
echo getBonus(4).PHP_EOL;  // 1000
echo getBonus(12).PHP_EOL; // 2000
echo getBonus(20).PHP_EOL; // 3000
echo getBonus(39).PHP_EOL; // 5000
```

P.S. `$bonuses` and `$stops` here **must** be equal length.

Comment: @RyanVincent with `array_reduce` I need to change the bonuses/stops logic, and I don't like both variants...  (just started with `array_map`)

Comment: Wasn't criticising - really was just curious - I would probably have used array_reduce - there is no 'one true way' :) will delete my comment soon

Comment: @RyanVincent Agree on `array_reduce` and agree on no 'one true way'!!